# How to test convergence for $\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^5}}{3x^2 +x +100}$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm new to these convergence tests, I've studied the quotient test and the comparison test for integrals, but I'm having difficulty using them, like for this integral $$\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^5}}{3x^2 +x +100} .$$

Is there something in this integral that I immediately should pay attention to, to make me understand which test I should be using and which function I should be choosing for the test?

Comment: Limit at infinity is infinity

Comment: $dx$ is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

The numerator has $x^{2.5}$ so the entire fraction is roughly $$\frac{x^{2.5}}{3x^2} = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{3}$$

Comment: I'm sorry but what about the $x+100$ ,and are you saying i should compare with $g(x)=\frac{1}{3\sqrt{x}}$ ?

Comment: @user3133165 yes, you should compare with $\sqrt{x}/3.$ The other terms in the denominator have lower degree and hence do no affect global behavior

Comment: @user3133165 : I think *gt6989b* means $\sqrt{x}/3$ and that it grows for $x\to\infty$ so that the integral grows infinite.

Comment: @user90369 thank you, fixed the arithmetic mistake

Comment: I compared with what you said and got that it diverges by the compassion test ,thank you .

Comment: @gt6989b : You are welcome. :-)